# how to create firefox plugin with the help of c++

Tags: c++, firefox, unix, plugins

hi
  I am having problem with creating firefox plugin.
  I know NPAPI.
  Please tell me how to create firefox plugin in c++ using NetScape plugin Application   Programming Interface.Tell me some basic code.

Comment: Why not write a Google-Chrome plugin? Much better documented.

Comment: @Quandary: I wasn't aware that Google Chrome plugins would work in Firefox. Do you have a link about that?

Comment: @CodyGray: In reality I was suggesting to use Chrome instead of FireFox.

Comment: @Quandary: I'm still not sure how that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Initialization_and_Destruction